# Symfony - Assets in dev mode

Tags: symfony, assets, development-environment

I am working through symfony tutorials and the documentation, it seems to imply that in dev mode  the resources are available without having to install the assets, something like:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ asset("bundles/yodauser/css/login.css") }}" />
```

I get a 404 error though in dev mode until I actually run the assets:install command.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: its [best practice](http://symfony.com/doc/current/best_practices/web-assets.html) to put all your assets in the `web` folder directly.  It saves just this sort of issue.

Comment: Ok thanks, I was under the misinformed impression (from the tutorial I am following) that the best practice was to put your assets in bundles.

Comment: np, its only fairly recent, so some tutorials are probably out of date.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Quoting documentation:

http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/templating.html#including-stylesheets-and-javascripts-in-twig

> You can also include assets located in your bundles' Resources/public
>   folder. You will need to run the php bin/console assets:install target
>   [--symlink] command, which moves (or symlinks) files into the correct
>   location. (target is by default "web").

```
<link href="{{ asset('bundles/acmedemo/css/contact.css') }}" rel="stylesheet" />
```

It should work, in my case sometimes it does sometimes it doeasnt.
Worst case scenario you will have to run command every time you update assets.

Comment: So is it only if using assetic for managing them that I dont need to do anything, or is it normal to always have to run install and dump when working in dev on windows?

Comment: it is normal, the best is to install them as symlinks. run the command with `--symlink` parameter.

Comment: Ok does that work on windows? I just assumed it didnt.

Comment: When I say assumed its because on the tutorial I am watching they keep saying, "use --symlink, unless youre on windows" which I thought didnt support symlinks.

Comment: It does, but of course best and fastest way to find out is to test it.

Comment: Ok I didnt bother because as I said she keeps saying "unless youre on windows", I will do thogh knowing that it works now, thanks.

Comment: In my case on most javascript assets it worked. But not always, sometimes i had to run command again. Dont rly know what was the reason.

Answer (score 3):

404 Error will be trough when the file don't exist on your server!(not found...) (W3 official doc [here](https://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec10.html)). The file don't exist in your target folder (or you target the wrong file ^^) ...

have you think to load your ressources in your web/ folder with this command:

```
# make a hard copy of the assets in web/
$ php app/console assets:install

# if possible, make absolute symlinks in web/ if not, make a hard copy
$ php app/console assets:install --symlink

# if possible, make relative symlinks in web/ if not, make a hard copy
$ php app/console assets:install --symlink --relative
```

This a new command on SF2.6 and you can find more samples of this command documentation [here](http://symfony.com/blog/new-in-symfony-2-6-smarter-assets-install-command)

you have [all the documentation of assetics](http://symfony.com/doc/2.8/cookbook/assetic/asset_management.html) on the officoal symfony website.
And few idea for the best practise [here](http://symfony.com/doc/current/best_practices/web-assets.html).

Also, it's better to use the **'** character in your asset() function like that :

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ asset('bundles/yodauser/css/login.css') }}" />
```

Comment: I prefer `app/console assets:install --symlink` as it avoids a copy and let changes through without reinstalling the assets all the time.

Comment: Yes, I Prefer too, I edit my post (the link for the cammand doc was wrong). thx.

Comment: Hey thanks, I understand what a 404 error is, I was not sure why I was getting it because I had thought the app dev mode would take care of the url mapping for me, so I had deleted the public assets directories thinking I didnt need them til production time.

Comment: Yes @Vardius told me that it is normal to have to dump\install even in dev mode, I incorrectly picked up that this was something I should only have to do in prod mode so I didnt understand why it only worked in dev if I did this. Cheers!